# "Project jdk is not defined" in an IntelliJ's 2016.3 JavaScript Project

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, configuration

After update to IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 I get the warning: "project jdk is not defined" in a JavaScript/Node/React project. Have I overseen something? How to solve it? Under "Setup JDK" link I cannot find any notes that fit.

Comment: It seems that projects give this warning if nothing is set for the Project SDK in Project Structure: Project Settings: Project: Project SDK field. JavaScript projects don't need this to be set but you could point it to a Java SDK or Ruby SDK etc to make the warning go away.

Comment: @WillHumphreys When I set the SDK through the Project Structure menu, the "project jdk is not defined " the notification didn't go away. I had to click the "Setup SDK" link in the notification itself.

Comment: @BrianGordon That's interesting. I have just tried adding and removing the a Java project sdk from a project just containing some HTML files and both methods work for me. I can make the notification appear and disappear whether I go through project structure or through the notification. My Intellij version is IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 Build #IU-163.7743.44.

Comment: This has been reported as [IDEA-164954](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164954).

Comment: Disabling the Scala plugin helps: [SCL-11105](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11105)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Scala Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, see this issue on the JetBrains bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11105

Quoting from the bug report:

> After upgrading to 2016.3 Ultimate, the editor windows show a yellow bar at the top that says "Project JDK is not defined" with a link to "Setup JDK" on my non-Java project. I don't want a JDK associated with this project because it's not a Java project. It's a small Docker project with Git version control. Please turn the message off.

User's comments:

> It turns out that the issue is related to the Scala plug-in. (...) I can confirm that disabling the Scala plugin made the error vanish.

If you don't want to disable the Scala plugin, as a workaround you can set up the project's SDK (even though it is not a Java project) by going to the project settings menu (*File*  ⃗ *Project Structure*  ⃗ *Project*) and selecting any SDK in the project SDK dropdown.

The bug ticket has been resolved, so the problem should not exist anymore if you have a recent version of IDEA and the Scala plugin.